# Which is the best way to emulate a balancer locally?

Tags: tomcat, networking, web-applications, load-balancing

Enviroment:

- SO: Windows
- App Server: 2 x Tomcat 7.0.32 (both run locally)

My application is deployed on two Tomcats, each one configured with a unique port (8081 and 8082).

I need a way to configure an new port (8080) and load balance between the two tomcats automatically.

Currently I am using the functionality *TCP/IP Monitor* that provides *Eclipse*, but this only allows me to manually routing.

I need this configuration to reproduce an error that occurs only in Prod Cluster. I'm considering using another Tomcat as balancer, but I'm not sure that this is the best option. Anyone has a better idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx with Upstream should be the best option for you. Look [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule). Its configuration is straightforward and you can use either round-robin or ip_hash (useful for sticky sessions), whichever scenario suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reproduce an error in prod, you should try to reproduce the same environment in dev. Assuming you are on tomcat 6 or higher, the three options that come to mind are
1. Load balancer
2. Apache front-end with mod_proxy
3. Apache front-end with mod_jk

Comment: Hi, I can't reproduce the same enviroment because in prod I have an F5 Load Balancer. I need a way to send load to both app servers randomly, does not have to be balanced. Thanks!